# Fetch a cell data by clicking another cell data from same row

Tags: php

I'm asking for a concept how to solve my problem. here is my problem, I have a table with 6 columns (id, filename , modified, size, type and download). This table is fetched using mysqli query and showed in a php file.

now, my download column has an image (same for each row). This image is actually a link. This link takes me to download.php page when I click on it.

**my requirement** is when the download image is clicked the filename for that row will be send along to the download.php. -------------------------how do I do that?

[image]

I'm asking for a concept more then code.

At first I though that, each image will be same in look but will have a different value. so when clicking, a unique image value will be used in the query "select filename from table_one where download=value" . but unfortunately I'm not sure this concept is possible. now question arise how do I add a value along with a image and how to retrieve it? ------  or is there a better solution ?

please tell me whether my concept is possible or help me giving a new concept to solve the problem.

---thanks.

Comment: you don't specify filenames in the links. you specify the id of the db record REPRESENTING that file. `<a href="download.php?id=XXX"><img src="download.gif" /></a>`

Comment: yes. if id can be passed I can retrieve filename using the id in download.php ......... wait while I do the code and test to see if it works.

Comment: @MarcB , good concept...... it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are iterating through your result set and generating the images, you could append `?id=[Table Id]` to the href attribute, therefore when you go to the download page you use `$_GET['id']` and you will be able to determine which download link the user clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id for that record with your first select statement, then send the id through the URL to the next page like so:

```
href="download.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"
```

Then on the download page you can get the id with:

```
$_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AJAX` and `jQuery` to get information from database without updating your page. Or generate static links with `GET` parameters.